# Write an R function to check if a matrix only contains 0's and 1's

Tags: r

Example

```
x <- rbind (c(1,0,0), c(0,1,1))
y <- rbind (c(1,2,0), c(0,0,1))
```

The function should return true for x and false for y.

To check if there are only 0's and 1's, I have tried using conditions...

```
all(x==1 || x==0) 
all(x==1 && x==0)
```

but they don't seem to work.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I have fixed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `%in%` with `all`.

```
apply_fun <- function(mat) all(mat %in% c(0, 1))

apply_fun(x)
#[1] TRUE

apply_fun(y)
#[1] FALSE
```

Or using `|`

```
apply_fun <- function(mat) all(mat == 0 | mat == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into `rle`.

```
all(rle(as.vector(x))$values %in% 0:1)
# [1] TRUE
all(rle(as.vector(y))$values %in% 0:1)
# [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sum` on a logical vector

```
apply_fun <- function(mat) sum(mat %in% c(0, 1)) == length(mat)
```